# exception 'BadMethodCallException' with message 'Method handleQueuedMessage does not exist.'

Tags: php, laravel, redis

I used redis as a queue for emails in my local environment for Laravel 4.3. I recently upgraded to Laravel 5.4, and when I attempt to use the redis queue (default) now:

```
php artisan queue:listen
```

I get a rapid succession of output statements like so:

```
Processing: mailer@handleQueuedMessage
```

with an error in the log file for each one:

```
exception 'BadMethodCallException' with message 'Method handleQueuedMessage does not exist.' in C:\xampp\htdocs\explore\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Support\Traits\Macroable.php:74
Stack trace:
#0 C:\xampp\htdocs\explore\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Queue\Jobs\Job.php(69): Illuminate\Mail\Mailer->__call('handleQueuedMes...', Array)
#1 C:\xampp\htdocs\explore\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Queue\Jobs\Job.php(69): Illuminate\Mail\Mailer->handleQueuedMessage(Object(Illuminate\Queue\Jobs\RedisJob), Array)
#2 C:\xampp\htdocs\explore\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Queue\Worker.php(317): Illuminate\Queue\Jobs\Job->fire()
#3 C:\xampp\htdocs\explore\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Queue\Worker.php(267): Illuminate\Queue\Worker->process('redis', Object(Illuminate\Queue\Jobs\RedisJob), Object(Illuminate\Queue\WorkerOptions))
#4 C:\xampp\htdocs\explore\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Queue\Worker.php(224): Illuminate\Queue\Worker->runJob(Object(Illuminate\Queue\Jobs\RedisJob), 'redis', Object(Illuminate\Queue\WorkerOptions))
#5 C:\xampp\htdocs\explore\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Queue\Console\WorkCommand.php(102): Illuminate\Queue\Worker->runNextJob('redis', 'default', Object(Illuminate\Queue\WorkerOptions))
#6 C:\xampp\htdocs\explore\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Queue\Console\WorkCommand.php(86): Illuminate\Queue\Console\WorkCommand->runWorker('redis', 'default')
#7 [internal function]: Illuminate\Queue\Console\WorkCommand->fire()
#8 C:\xampp\htdocs\explore\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\BoundMethod.php(30): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#9 C:\xampp\htdocs\explore\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\BoundMethod.php(87): Illuminate\Container\BoundMethod::Illuminate\Container\{closure}()
#10 C:\xampp\htdocs\explore\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\BoundMethod.php(31): Illuminate\Container\BoundMethod::callBoundMethod(Object(Illuminate\Foundation\Application), Array, Object(Closure))
#11 C:\xampp\htdocs\explore\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Container.php(539): Illuminate\Container\BoundMethod::call(Object(Illuminate\Foundation\Application), Array, Array, NULL)
#12 C:\xampp\htdocs\explore\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Console\Command.php(182): Illuminate\Container\Container->call(Array)
#13 C:\xampp\htdocs\explore\vendor\symfony\console\Command\Command.php(264): Illuminate\Console\Command->execute(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Illuminate\Console\OutputStyle))
#14 C:\xampp\htdocs\explore\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Console\Command.php(168): Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command->run(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Illuminate\Console\OutputStyle))
#15 C:\xampp\htdocs\explore\vendor\symfony\console\Application.php(869): Illuminate\Console\Command->run(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
#16 C:\xampp\htdocs\explore\vendor\symfony\console\Application.php(223): Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRunCommand(Object(Illuminate\Queue\Console\WorkCommand), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
#17 C:\xampp\htdocs\explore\vendor\symfony\console\Application.php(130): Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRun(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
#18 C:\xampp\htdocs\explore\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel.php(122): Symfony\Component\Console\Application->run(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
#19 C:\xampp\htdocs\explore\artisan(36): Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel->handle(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
#20 {main}
```

I did a google search for this method, and found it nowhere. My email queue does function properly, but I am lost as to why this message is appearing. Has anyone experienced this that can shed some light on the issue?

Here is my relevant app/database.php:

```
<?php


    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Redis Databases
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Redis is an open source, fast, and advanced key-value store that also
    | provides a richer set of commands than a typical key-value systems
    | such as APC or Memcached. Laravel makes it easy to dig right in.
    |
    */

    'redis' => [

        'client' => 'predis',

        'default' => [
            'host' => env('REDIS_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
            'password' => env('REDIS_PASSWORD', null),
            'port' => env('REDIS_PORT', 6379),
            'database' => 0,
        ],

    ],
```

and my relevant app/queue.php:

```
<?php

return [

    'default' => env('QUEUE_DRIVER', 'redis'),

    'connections' => [

        'redis' => [
            'driver' => 'redis',
            'connection' => 'default',
            'queue' => 'default',
            'retry_after' => 90,
        ],

    ],

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Failed Queue Jobs
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | These options configure the behavior of failed queue job logging so you
    | can control which database and table are used to store the jobs that
    | have failed. You may change them to any database / table you wish.
    |
    */

    'failed' => [
        'database' => env('DB_CONNECTION', 'mysql'),
        'table' => 'failed_jobs',
    ],

];
```

and the relevant .env:

```
QUEUE_DRIVER=redis

REDIS_HOST=127.0.0.1
REDIS_PASSWORD=null
REDIS_PORT=6379
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you run `composer dumpautoload` after the upgrade or changed anything?

Comment: yes sir, I've run composer dump-autoload many times since the upgrade. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Please include your relevant queue code, just dumping random config files here is not going to get you much help. Select which parts of the config are essential

Comment: Hi milo,  I added the configs only because I thought someone might request them. The queue code should not be necessary as it's open-source that's being used by numerous websites/businesses, and is definitely not the issue. Thanks for your feedback.

Answer (score 0):

This is an issue related to the following Laravel framework threads:
https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/9881
https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/11892

Specifically, there was an issue with a previous email not rendering correctly and continuing to be attempted by the Redis queue without ever receiving instructions to try a finite number of times before marking as Failed.

The following command resolved it:

```
php artisan queue:work --daemon --tries=1
```

Output:

```
[2017-07-28 06:48:13] Processing: mailer@handleQueuedMessage
[2017-07-28 06:48:13] Failed:     mailer@handleQueuedMessage
```

Hopefully this will assist others who encounter this.